# Observer Pattern of Java API :subject if extended

Tags: design-patterns, observer-pattern, java

In Java built-in API for Observer Pattern we have to extend Observable class to become\implement "subject". I wanted to know if i extend the class implementing "Observable" will also become a "Subject\Observable" and if so will it inherit all the observers from the parent?

Ex: Class A extends Observable

Class B extends A

So B is also Observable/subject?

Comment: Why don't you try to extend it and see what happens in a debugger?

Comment: What do you expect to happen?  Have you tried it before asking? I hate having to use the down vote arrow, but your post doesn't show that you tried it before asking.

Comment: hmmm....i don't have a ready code to test.. was reading about it and wanted to know if anyone has done this.

Comment: Stack Overflow should not be a first port of call. If anything it should be a last port of call once you have exhausted all other ways of answering your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you are absolutely correct.
If Class A extends Observable and Class B extends A it does makes Class B Observable. 
You should be able to test this with below sample test code.

```
import java.util.Observable;

import java.util.Observer;

public class TestObserve extends Object {
    MyView view;
    TestObservableA testObservableA;
    TestObservableB testObservableB;
    public TestObserve() {

        view = new MyView();

        testObservableA = new TestObservableA();
        testObservableA.addObserver(view);

        testObservableB = new TestObservableB();
        testObservableB.addObserver(view);
    }

    public static void main(String[] av) {
        TestObserve testObserve = new TestObserve();
        testObserve.testExtend();
    }

    public void testExtend() {
        testObservableA.changeSomething();
        testObservableB.changeSomething();
    }

    class MyView implements Observer {
        public void update(Observable observable, Object x) {
            System.out.println("Test Update(" + observable + "," + x + ");");
        }
    }

    class TestObservableA extends Observable {
        public void changeSomething() {
            setChanged();
            notifyObservers();
        }
    }

    class TestObservableB extends TestObservableA {
        public void changeSomething() {
            setChanged();
            notifyObservers();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you!! That's all i needed to know.